# Create Separate Cache for every URL in FastCGI

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

Problem with FastCGI Cache

Currently, the Query URL is like this.

**Correct API URL:** example.com/api/123456 (TRUE)

**Wrong API URI:** example.com/api/1234885 (This also gives True Because it's serving the cached version)

**My Use Case:**
Upon every request to the webserver by the end-user. The webserver requests my API End Point which matches the API Key and Domain Name then authenticates it and makes the function work and serve the user.

**Problem:**
When the API hits for the first time with the correct API Key. It returns TRUE. Which is cached and stored.
If another user trying with an Invalid or wrong API key. It keeps serving the cached version (True Value) instead of querying from the database.

What I want to Achieve? How to save `example.com/api/123456` and `example.com/api/123888` as different cached version.

Because I don't wanna authenticate someone with the wrong API Key because of cache.

Please Share alternative ideas if you have.